# Writing data from Android to a MySQL database showing me errors

Tags: php, android, mysql, performance, apache

Hi im working on a college project to make a new record in the database each time the user fills in the information and clicks on the register button . im using apache server , php and mysql database as well as java . i have the php files saved in the apache folder and im using the localhost to call these files.
i also used jason class to view data.

My problem is :
each time i fill in the information and click on the register button the app fails to create a record in the database , i have searched everywhere for a solution but i didnt find any , i hope someone can help me .
Thanks In Advance.

**this is the code of the Register page:**

```
package tigris.codes.Registration.system;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Registration extends Activity {
    //Declaring Variables
    EditText StudentName,StudentEmail,StudentPassword,StudentMobNumber,StudentNumber;
    Button RegisterButton;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://localhost/android_connect/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        //Linking Objects
        StudentName         =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegNameEditText);
        StudentEmail        =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegEmailEditText);
        StudentPassword     =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPasswordEditText);
        StudentMobNumber    =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPhoneEditText);
        StudentNumber       =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegStudentNumber);
        RegisterButton      =   (Button)   findViewById(R.id.registerUserButton);


        //Setting Button Event
        RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        }); 
    }//End of onCreate method




    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Registration.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name      = StudentName.getText().toString();
            String password  = StudentPassword.getText().toString();
            String email     = StudentEmail.getText().toString();
            String phone     = StudentMobNumber.getText().toString();
            String snumber   = StudentNumber.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("snumber", snumber));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.registration, menu);
        return true;
    }//end of boolean onCreateOptionMenu

}//end of main class
```

**These are the errors that i got in the log-cat:**

```
10-24 13:44:49.141: E/Buffer Error(1520): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
10-24 13:44:49.161: E/JSON Parser(1520): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at tigris.codes.attendance.system.Registration$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(Registration.java:107)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at tigris.codes.attendance.system.Registration$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(Registration.java:1)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     ... 4 more
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520): Activity tigris.codes.attendance.system.Registration has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cff448 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-329,175} that was originally added here
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity tigris.codes.attendance.system.Registration has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cff448 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-329,175} that was originally added here
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at tigris.codes.attendance.system.Registration$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(Registration.java:80)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at tigris.codes.attendance.system.Registration$1.onClick(Registration.java:57)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-24 13:44:52.711: E/WindowManager(1520):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please do not do this `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);` you are not in the main thread, do it in the onPostExecute

Comment: @A.S. i did that but that still doesn't fix my problem . Thanks though :)

Comment: whats in this line 10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 13:44:49.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1520):     at tigris.codes.attendance.system.Registration$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(Registration.java:107)